# ensembldb equivalent in python

Tags: bioconductor, python

Is there a python equivalent to [ensembldb](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ensembldb.html)? I want to get genome coordinates for a transcript (like the function `transcriptToGenome`) but need to do it in python. I wrote a R script that I'm calling from python but I was hoping there was a more direct way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`pyensembl` should do the job:

```
>>> from pyensembl import EnsemblRelease
>>> data = EnsemblRelease(76)
>>> data.transcript_by_id("ENST00000506751")
Transcript(..., contig='5', start=140861224, end=140863521, strand='+', genome='GRCh38')
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is perfect. Do you happen to know if there is anything similar for NCBI?

Comment: Maybe https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Entrez.html?

Comment: I don't see a way to map coordinates with Bio.Entrez unfortunately.  Thanks though.